# How to get fancybox to open a php

Tags: php, fancybox

I'm trying to get fancybox to open a php file; the file contains this code `<?php echo "hi"; ?>`.
Now when I set the image href attribute to a jpeg file it loads fine. But when I set it to a php file it doesn't load. Can I have help trying to get it to load a php file.

`<a class= "fancyimg" href="http://mydomain.com/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4/count.php" ><img src="http://mydomain.com/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4/fancyimg2.jpg">`

Here is part of my code

```
       <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".fancyimg").fancybox({
            'overlayShow'   : false,
            'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
            'transitionOut' : 'elastic'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use type attribute of fancybox as below to open php file.

```
$(".fancyimg").fancybox({
 'width'        : '75%',
 'height'       : '75%',
 'autoScale'        : false, 
 'type'         : 'iframe',
 'overlayShow'   : false,
 'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
 'transitionOut' : 'elastic'
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Shahid Ahmed.... I have noticed one problem with taking this approach. If I include a file in count.php for example. the image is clicked the whole page that I included displays in the fancy box. Any ideas why ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like this :

```
$(".fancyimg").click(function() {
    $.fancybox.open({
        href : $(this).attr("data-id"),
        type : 'iframe',
        padding : 5
    });
});
```

and instead of href="http://mydomain.com/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4/count.php" put your link in a custom attribute called data-id like this :

```
<a class= "fancyimg" href="#" data-id="http://mydomain.com/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4/count.php" ><img src="http://mydomain.com/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4/fancyimg2.jpg"></a>
```